# Is publishing to AWS different between node react or express?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I am  a complete noob here but I am getting ready to publish my app on AWS and I am curious what the major differences is between the libraries in regard to publishing them?
ARe there recommendation on better libraries to use?

Comment: Opinion-based questions and questions seeking recommendations for libraries or other off-site resources are explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow per the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: What do you mean by "ARe there recommendation on better libraries to use?" Are you asking if you should use something other than express and react? I think that sentence is why you are getting downvotes. React is a front-end library, express is a back-end library, so there are definitely differences in how you would deploy those to AWS.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** publishing to **Amazon Web Service** (AWS) is not different between node react or express.You can deploy a MERN stack app on AWS
[This](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/18/react-nodejs-on-aws-how-to-deploy-a-mern-stack-app-to-amazon-ec2) is a valuable blog which I found on internet